# How to get higher quality images from eBay API

Tags: django, image, ebay-api

I am currently working in Django and getting some data from eBay API. The API gives me image URL, but the problem is that the quality of image is 70px, which is low.

Is there any method where I can get image of higher quality? I need images with minimum 200px. eBay has higher quality images (same image with high quality which they gives in their API).

I am using `getTopSellingProducts` call to retrieve them.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to break the bad news, but from eBay API [getTopSellingProducts documentation](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/merchandising/docs/CallRef/getTopSellingProducts.html#Response.productRecommendations.product.imageURL):

> Fully qualified URL for a stock image (if any) associated with the
>   eBay catalog product. The URL is for the image eBay usually displays
>   in product search results **(usually 70px tall).** It may be helpful
>   to calculate the dimensions of the photo programmatically before
>   displaying it. Only returned if a URL is available for the product.